# Check if a number is a digit in a number column SQL

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a table with a column of DR. ID #'s. I want all the rows that have a 2 in them.

| first_name | dr_id |
| --- | --- |
| joe | 534 |
| eric | 267 |
| allen | 309 |
| steven | 125 |
| gary | 11 |

I have been searching for a number version of substring but I can't find it.
The only other idea would be to change the values to string then do a substring search. Is there another way?

Comment: only one 2 in dr_id?

Comment: Convert the ID to a char or varchar, and then use `LIKE`.

Comment: @Ken White, I suppose the OP wants to do the search using its numeric form rather than its string form, which I personally think is not possible in this case.

Comment: @blabla_bingo: It's not possible to do it in numeric form, which is why I suggested the only way that will work.

Comment: Hard to see how this requirement could actually arise in practice.

Comment: @ user207421 it arose in an interview. Hard to see why you wasted time writing a comment that helps no one.

Comment: @FernandoAraiza Hard to see why you would omit the fact that it was an interview question, or why you don't understand my comment as a simple request for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a number's inherent trait is it's eligible for mathematical operations. So if you want to define a search condition based on a number's numeric form, then make sure it's possible to define the search condition by performing a mathematical calculation on it. For instance, if we want to `find a number which can be divided by 2`,we can use `WHERE num mod 2 =0 and num<>0` .

But in this case, I'm not sure the condition `find a number which has a 2 in it` can be proved by a math operation. Therefore, using a string function(or REGEXP) is probably the only choice. Here I would suggest using `locate(substr,str)` funtion, which returns 0 if substr is not in str or NULL if any argument is NULL:

```
select * from tb where locate('2',dr_id)>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use string functions, where the number will automatically be casted to a string/char. e.g:

```
SELECT 123 LIKE "%2%" CONTAINS_2;
+------------+
| CONTAINS_2 |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+

SELECT LOCATE("3", 123) > 0 CONTAINS_3;
+------------+
| CONTAINS_3 |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+

SELECT INSTR(123, "1") > 0 CONTAINS_1;
+------------+
| CONTAINS_1 |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```